# Find a child of a node in a node collection

Tags: c#, xpath

i am new to Xpath and i am trying to find a child node of each of the nodes i have stored in a `HtmlNodeCollection`

To be more specific i have this collection: `HtmlNodeCollection Results = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id = 'SearchResults']//div[@class = 'AdvItemBox']");`
and inside each `"AdvItemBox"` there is a `div` with `class='AdvNameHeader'`

I have alrady tried this code but it keeps returning the 1st child it finds:

```
HtmlNodeCollection Results = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id = 'SearchResults']//div[@class = 'AdvItemBox']");
            StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (HtmlNode item in Results)
            {
                HtmlNode itemName = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id = 'SearchResults']//div[@class = 'AdvItemBox']//div[@class = 'AdvNameHeader']");
                strb.AppendFormat("Name: {0}{1}", Regex.Replace(item.InnerText, @"\s+", ""), Environment.NewLine);

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `item` as the starting point for the query within the loop, and use a relative XPath:

```
HtmlNodeCollection Results = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id = 'SearchResults']//div[@class = 'AdvItemBox']");
StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (HtmlNode item in Results)
{
    HtmlNode itemName = item.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class = 'AdvNameHeader']");
    strb.AppendFormat("Name: {0}{1}", Regex.Replace(item.InnerText, @"\s+", ""), Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: @evans: Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.